# Freezing on Upload by API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload big file with the Dropbox API, I am using the code from this example

[GitHub](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/upload-file/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/upload_file/Main.java)

(Edit) (I have try to upload 16MB and 200MB files) freeze at the 122 line of the example from the GitHub.

I am using dropbox-core-sdk-3.0.3.jar

I am doing anything wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the example of the GitHub, I have lower the CHUNKED SIZE to 1MB and now it is working.